# how to get change string "R.drawable.someimage" to an id?

Tags: java, android

```
String path = "R.drawable.pic_" + 4;
imageOfPages.setImageResource(path);
```

but it needs id not String.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier("pic_" + 4, "drawable", getPackageName());
 if (id > 0) {

 }
```

From the documentation:

> ```
>  Return a resource identifier for the given resource name.
> ```